# How can I add large files to a Git repo?

Tags: git

I have a Microsoft Azure / Visual studio online repo managed with Git.
I am using the Git GUI application to manage it.

I have a couple of files that are 535 MB and 620 MB in size. I would like to add these to the repo.

I have enabled Git large file support, and i have set the global post buffer with the command:

`git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000`

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to add these files. 
The commit is fine, but when I push to the remote branch, I get:

```
POST git-receive-pack (547584390 bytes)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 503 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 503
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

As far as I know, adjusting the buffer like this should work in this case. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems that you have added the large files just fine, but that your remote does not accept that amount of data. This is thus not a programming question.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. It is a Git question, rather than a programming question. I will adjust the title to more qccurately reflect what I am asking.

Comment: “have enabled Git large file support” How?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed this:  https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: Ok but that’s for GitHub. You are not using GitHub.

Comment: @matt It works for Azure DevOps services too: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/announcing-git-lfs-on-all-vso-git-repos/

Comment: Consider using a universal package feed instead of putting these large files in source control.

Answer (score 1):

Activating LFS locally ([`git-lfs.github.com`](https://git-lfs.github.com/) as you mention) is a good first step.

Check also the prerequisites and limitations at [Azure DevOps Azure Repos / Use Git Large File Storage (LFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-large-files?view=azure-devops#use-git-large-file-storage-lfs)

Finally, if you just added/committed the large file, it is better to reset that commit (assuming you don't have any other work in progress), and then [track it through lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47200501/6309):

```
git reset @~
git lfs track lyLargeFile
git
```

Answer (score 1):

After fighting with git for weeks, I have finally solved this.

the answer for me was to clone the repo again using SSH instead of HTTP.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know there was size limitation through HTTPS only.

Comment: It may be to do with my internet connection being flaky / slow. Seems SSH is much more stable for long upload times